# Liferay 6.1 facebook SSO update

Tags: facebook-graph-api, liferay, liferay-6

Facebook SSO is not working in Liferay 6.1. 
Maybe is due the change to API Graph v2.3 But I don't know if there is a fix in Liferay to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you refer to Liferay 6.1 CE. The last update to that version is from 2013 and it's been end-of-lifed back with that update and the release of Liferay 6.2. You don't even mention which exact 6.1 version you're running, but I assume that this happened recently.

6.1 EE still receives limited support, but if you would run that version, I'd assume that you'd rather have filed a ticket with the Enterprise Support Team than posting a question on stackoverflow.

That's a long way to say: The last update for Liferay 6.1 CE was in 2013 and there are and will be no further fixes for any issues of that versions under a 6.1.x version number. The updates that exist carry the version numbers 6.2 (end-of-lifed in 2016) and 7.0 (currently in GA3) and you should try out the latest version if the issue appears there as well.

Comment: Is there any workaround? Migrate to 7.0 is not easy way.

Comment: The longer you wait, the harder it gets. You're already running on a software from 2013. Of course, you can look at the source code (it's all on github) and check if this is fixed in a later version, then backport the change to your version. That won't be simple either though. And you've asked if there *is* a fix - *If* there *is*, it would be in the latest version, or you're responsible to fix it yourself after end-of-life of a version you're using. If you need a longer maintenance cycle: EE (from 7.0 on it's called DXP) has support up to 7 years from release